# Getting year-end values from prior year on each result row of MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, msbi, cube-script

I have a snapshot fact table with a time grain of monthly and so the measure values are only point in time, not cumulative over time.  I need to derive a Previous Year-End value to compare any given month's values to the end of the previous year like so:

| Month  | Val1 | PrevYEVal |

| 2014-10 |  101 |       100 |

| 2014-11 |  103 |       100 |

| 2014-12 |  105 |       100 |

| 2015-01 |  110 |       105 |

| 2015-02 |  115 |       105 |

| 2015-03 |  113 |       105 |

...

| 2015-12 |  120 |       105 |

| 2016-01 |  130 |       120 |

etc...

I'm using SSAS and the time dimension table is set up as such with a Year->Quarter->Month->Day hierarchy.

I can find solutions to a previous month, a rolling number of months and getting a YTD cumulative value but this is a straight up point in time to point in time comparison.

I'm trying to use Lag, Ancestor, and/or ParallelPeriod but I can't seem to get the above result set.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Create member CurrentCube.[Measures].[PrevYEVal] as null;
Scope([Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Month].Members);
  [Measures].[PrevYEVal]=([Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent.Parent.PrevMember.LastChild.LastChild, [Measures].[Val1]);
End scope;
```

Comment: ...off topic but I was wondering if you have ever encountered this challenge Greg? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485982/top-x-of-top-y-with-restof-member-where-x-and-y-are-unrelated-hierarchies