# Top X of Top Y with RestOf member where X and Y are hierarchies from different dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

This works fine:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllStates]    AS [State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top2States] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries]
     ,TopCount
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [AllStates])
       ,3
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [State-Province].[All].[RestOfCountry] AS 
    Aggregate({(EXISTING {[AllStates]} - [Top2States])}) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
      [AllCountries]
    * 
      {
        [State-Province].[All]
       ,[Top2States]
       ,[State-Province].[All].[RestOfCountry]
      }
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The `EXISTING` keyword helps a lot .

If the two hierarchies `ON ROWS` are not from the same dimension, in the way that countries and states are in the above, then we have something like the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllCats]      AS [Product].[Category].[Category].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Cats] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries]
     ,TopCount
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [AllCats])
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Category].[All].[RestOfProds] AS 
    Aggregate({(EXISTING {[AllCats]} - [Top5Cats])}) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
      [AllCountries]
    * 
      {
        [Product].[Category].[All]
       ,[Top5Cats]
       ,[Product].[Category].[All].[RestOfCountry]

      }
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

You can see in the results of the above that the same set of categories are repeated against each country, in the same order i.e. the engine is not finding the topCount per country. `EXISTING` is now redundant.

How can we adapt the second script above so that it has similar functionality as the top script?

---

**Edit**

A better example is the following using Product. It is as if the engine is finding the `TopCount` for All countries and then putting the same set against each country. I'd like the `TopCount` for each country:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS 
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllProds] AS 
    [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Prods] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries]
     ,TopCount
      (
        (EXISTING 
          [AllProds])
       ,5
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds] AS 
    Aggregate({(EXISTING {[AllProds]} - [Top5Prods])}) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [AllCountries]
      * 
        {
          [Product].[Product].[All]
         ,[Top5Prods]
         ,[Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds]
        }
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

**Edit2**

This is the latest version via Sourav's ideas - unfortunately the RestOfProds members are not functioning correctly:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS 
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllProds] AS 
    [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Prods] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries] AS a
     ,
        {
            (
              a.Current
             ,[Product].[Product].[All]
            )
          + 
            //The top x prods
            TopCount
            (
              NonEmpty
              (
                a.Current * [AllProds]
               ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
              )
             ,5
             ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            )
        }
    ) 
  SET [RestOfProds] AS 
    Extract
    (
      {[AllCountries] * [AllProds]} - [Top5Prods]
     ,[Product].[Product]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds] AS 
    Aggregate([RestOfProds]) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Top5Prods]
   ,
    [AllCountries] * [Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

**Edit3**

The following has the correct order so that the member `RestOfProds` always follows it's respective top 5

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS 
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllProds] AS 
    [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Prods] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries] AS a
     ,{
        //The top x prods
        TopCount
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
            a.Current * [AllProds]
           ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          )
         ,5
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds] AS 
    Aggregate([Country].CurrentMember * [AllProds] - [Top5Prods]) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Generate
  (
    [AllCountries] AS X
   ,
      Order
      (
        Intersect
        (
          X.CurrentMember * [AllProds]
         ,[Top5Prods]
        )
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
       ,bdesc
      )
    + 
      {X.CurrentMember * {[Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds]}}
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

---

**Edit4**

The following has the correct order so that the member `RestOfProds` always follows it's respective top 5 + I've added a further set on rows:

```
WITH 
  SET [2months] AS 
    {
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[9]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[10]
    } 
  SET [AllCountries] AS 
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [MthsCountries] AS 
    [2months] * [AllCountries] 
  SET [AllProds] AS 
    [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Prods] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [MthsCountries] AS A
     ,{
        //The top x prods
        TopCount
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
            A.Current * [AllProds]
           ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          )
         ,5
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        ([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,[Country].CurrentMember) * [AllProds]
      - 
        [Top5Prods]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Generate
  (
    [MthsCountries] AS X
   ,
      Order
      (
        Intersect
        (
          X.Current * [AllProds]
         ,[Top5Prods]
        )
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
       ,bdesc
      )
    + 
      {X.Current * {[Product].[Product].[All].[RestOfProds]}}
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXISTING` when used on named sets, doesn't really make a difference since named sets are created before the axes members are laid out. In your case, `GENERATE` is really just creating static sets and then on the axes everything is just cross joined.

To get the `TopCount` script working, you need to handle all the `cross joins` inside one set so that everything is evaluated together. I am not sure, but you might try the below:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllCats]    AS [Product].[Category].[Category].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Cats] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries] as a
     ,
     {
     (a.current , [Product].[Category].[All] ) //The ALL member
     +   
     TopCount  //The top 2 categories
      (
        NonEmpty((a.current * [AllCats] ) , (a.CURRENT, [Measures].[Internet Order Count]))
       ,2
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]      
      ) 
      }
    + 
    { //The rest of the members
    a.current * [AllCats] 
    - 
    a.current *{     
     TopCount
      (
        NonEmpty([AllCats] , (a.CURRENT, [Measures].[Internet Order Count]))
       ,2
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]      
      ) 
      }
      }
    )

  MEMBER [Product].[Category].[All].[RestOfProds] AS 
    Aggregate({(EXISTING {[AllCats]} - [Top5Cats])}) 

SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS,
[Top5Cats] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

**EDIT:**
If you need the `RestOfCats` member, you can add this code.

```
SET [RestOfCats] AS
EXTRACT
    (
     {
     [AllCountries] * [AllCats] 
     - 
     [Top5Cats]
     },
     [Product].[Category]
    )

MEMBER [Product].[Category].[All].[RestOfCats] AS
Aggregate([RestOfCats])
```

**EDIT 2**

Continuing on your example, removing the 'All' member additionally in the definition.

```
  SET [RestOfProds] AS 
    Extract
    (
      {[AllCountries] * [AllProds]} - [Top5Prods] - [AllCountries]*[Product].[Product].[All]
     ,[Product].[Product]
    )
```

Comment: (upped) although this is still not working `RestOfProds`

Comment: Do you mean to say that `{ 
    a.current * [AllCats] 
    - 
    a.current *{     
     TopCount
      (
        NonEmpty([AllCats] , (a.CURRENT, [Measures].[Internet Order Count]))
       ,2
       ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]      
      ) 
      }` part is ineffective?

Comment: that section you mentioned _is_ effective: but this is not being used as in the original script `[Product].[Category].[All].[RestOfProds]` and I need the "RestOf" member to function.

Comment: If you have to have the member, have it like in the edited code .

Comment: looks promising: let me test - I think I'll switch to Product rather than Category as Category only has a limited number of members.

Comment: why did you include the section `//The rest of the members...` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94103/discussion-between-sourava-and-whytheq).

Comment: still just getting the All member back

Comment: hmmm - this post might help us? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8758b97-eeb6-4e9c-bef9-9e721f7c8072/in-top-10-with-two-dimension-i-need-to-add-others-in-my-mdx-query?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Answer (score 1):

If you are crossjoining multiple hierarchies in the same dimension only valid combinations will be shown. This is called auto-exists and it explains why the first query works like you want.

When crossjoining hierarchies from different dimensions the auto-exists does not happen. I think this explains the odd combinations returned in the second query.

Try adding NON EMPTY at the beginning of your ON ROWS definition. Then it will only return combinations which have an Internet Order Count measure value (whatever measures are on columns). That's the proper way to limit the crossjoin.

If you don't want a NON EMPTY on Internet Order Count then so you need a NonEmpty(, [Measures].[A Different Measure]) on a different measure?

Edit: It looks like the issue is not related to auto-exists but is related to performing a different TopCount per country. So this info may help someone else but isn't the answer to this question.

Comment: thanks for the help although unfortunately it isn't so simple. Adding `NON EMPTY` gets rid of the blank rows but let me change Category to Product and you can see that the same set of Products is repeated against each country: I think it is find the `TopCount` for `All` countries and then using that against each country.

Comment: Looks like I oversimplified the problem in this case and that SouravA is onto the solution related to a TopCount.

Comment: I've added the latest version to the original question - it is close but the RestOfProd members are still not correct

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work ok:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS 
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllProds] AS 
    [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Prods] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries] AS a
     ,{
          (
            a.CurrentMember
           ,[Product].[Product].[All]
          )
        + 
            //The top x prods
            a.CurrentMember
          * 
            TopCount
            (
              [AllProds]
             ,5
             ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            )
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All].[Other Products] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        [Country].CurrentMember * [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS
      - 
        [Top5Prods]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize(
    {
     [Top5Prods]
    ,[AllCountries] * [Product].[Product].[All].[Other Products]
    }
) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: I had an answer ready, but it seems you got it. Yes, I think you need to use the `currentmember` function to get the "RestOf" member. +1d yours

Comment: @SouravA just trying to order the ROWS in the correct order now! .. partitioned by country with the All member first, then the top5, then the Other Products member. As it stands it is chucking all of the Other Products at the end of the cellset.