# Ranking of multiple dimensions, restarting for every year

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a measure, Sales Amount.  I want to rank customers within a divison by year for that measure.  I need to also display that rank as a measure.  The rank needs to start over every year.  I am able to do customers by year and customers by division, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine them both so it iterates over both dimensions properly.  Below is what I have for the customers by year.  I have tried adding another Division set, creating another named set that I `GENERATE` with the YearsWithCustomers set, and `RANK` using that new named set.  I seem to be super close to figuring this out but I think I am putting something in the wrong place.  I got the idea to iterate over a set from one of Chris Webb's blogs, [located here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2007/06/25/advanced-ranking-and-dynamically-generated-named-sets-in-mdx/).

```
WITH 
  SET Years AS 
    TopPercent
    (
      [Sales and Forecast Date].[Calendar Year].[Year Number].MEMBERS
     ,100
     ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
    ) 
  SET Customers AS 
    Filter
    (
      [Customer].[Customer Number].[Customer Number].MEMBERS
     ,
      [Measures].[Sales Amount] > 0
    ) 
  SET YearsWithCustomers AS 
    Generate
    (
      Years
     ,Union
      (
        {[Sales and Forecast Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember}
       ,StrToSet
        ("
            Intersect({},
           {order(Customers,([Sales Amount],[Sales and Forecast Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember),desc)
            as CustomerSet"
            + 
              Cstr(Years.CurrentOrdinal)
          + "})"
        )
      )
     ,ALL
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Customer Rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [Customer].[Customer Number].CurrentMember
     ,StrToSet
      ("CustomerSet"
        + 
          Cstr
          (
            Rank
            (
              [Sales and Forecast Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember
             ,Years
            )
          )
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Customer Rank]
   ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,Order
  (
    Filter
    (
      (
        YearsWithCustomers
       ,Customers
      )
     ,
      [Sales Amount] > 0
    )
   ,[Sales Amount]
   ,desc
  ) ON 1
FROM [OrdersAndBudgets];
```

Here is what I currently have.  I would expect to see 1, 2, 3, etc for the Rank measure.  It should reset for each division for every year.

[image: Example with wrong results]

Answer (score 1):

I like this sort of pattern:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllCountries] AS 
    [Country].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllProds] AS 
    [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
  SET [Top5Prods] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [AllCountries] AS a
     ,{
          (
            a.CurrentMember
           ,[Product].[Product].[All]
          )
        + 
            //The top x prods
            a.CurrentMember
          * 
            TopCount
            (
              [AllProds]
             ,5
             ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            )
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Product].[Product].[All].[Other Products] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        [Country].CurrentMember * [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS
      - 
        [Top5Prods]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize(
    {
     [Top5Prods]
    ,[AllCountries] * [Product].[Product].[All].[Other Products]
    }
) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the following:

[image]

There is quite an extensive thread here: [Top X of Top Y with RestOf member where X and Y are hierarchies from different dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485982/top-x-of-top-y-with-restof-member-where-x-and-y-are-hierarchies-from-different-d)

Comment: I need to have the rank as a measure, as well as all members ranked.  Top X will be handled on the reporting side so they can dynamically chose what X is.  I have included a picture as an example.